# Shorter code so fill arrays with same Value

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, gridview

For my "memory" game, I'm using a GridView to display 12 cards.
At the beginning, the cards are all the same.

In all the examples I found, you see something similar to this code to add the picture ids to your ImageAdapter:

```
 private Integer[] mThumbIds = {     
        R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
        R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
        R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
        R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
        R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
        R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back
    };
```

Is there a shorter,cleaner, nicer way?
something like this:

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = new Integer[11];
Arrays.fill(mThumbIds, R.drawable.card_back);
```

full class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images

    Integer[] mThumbIds = new Integer[11];
    Arrays.fill(mThumbIds, R.drawable.card_back);


       /*   R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
            R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
            R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
            R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
            R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back,
            R.drawable.card_back, R.drawable.card_back
    };*/

}
```

Comment: Did you *try* that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that's exactly it - you can use [`java.util.Arrays#fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-int:A-int-):

```
Arrays.fill(mThumbIds, R.drawable.card_back);
```

Comment: ok, but im getting these errors: 
Syntax error on token "(", < expected
Syntax error, insert ">" to complete Reference
Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName

Comment: @Klaus please post your full code and the exact error in the question. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: `Arrays.fill` is not a valid statement. You can't use in the class scope like you were declaring a member. Put that line of code in your constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to initialize your array:

```
int arr[] = new int[12]; // 0 ... 11
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = R.drawable.card_back;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, to low rep to commment @Mureinik answer.
Usually to keep my constructors clean and initialize variables that are always the same for all instances i do it this way:

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = new Integer[11];
{
    Arrays.fill(mThumbIds, R.drawable.card_back);
}
```

This block gets called per instance before the constructor.